# In the US, did party conventions reduce the political power of the states?

Tags: united-states, parties

The creation of [national party conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_nominating_convention) in the early 1830s allowed broader participation in nominating presidential candidates but, I wonder, did they reduce the political power of the states?